# Passing random engine through a function - why different compiler behaves differently

Tags: c++, c++11

For your convenient to illustrate this issue, I made the minimalist codes as below. The codes look innocent but the results are surprising! I tried on different compiler on my Mac and PC. The gcc seems fine but the clang provides incorrect results. My guess is that it may be some undefined behavior. The Mac results show repeat pattern of non-random number. Why this happens?

Here are the codes

```
#include <iostream>
#include<random>
using namespace std;

class FillUpX{
public:
    FillUpX(default_random_engine eng):generator{eng}{};
    void printValue(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
            cout << rnorm(generator) << endl;
        }
    }

private:
    default_random_engine & generator;
    std::normal_distribution<> rnorm{0,1};
};


int main(){

    unsigned seed=10;
    std::default_random_engine gen{seed};


    FillUpX fhd(gen);
    fhd.printValue();

   return 0;
}
```

Here are the outputs

```
-0.361197
1.67039
-0.361197
1.67039
-0.361197
1.67039
-0.361197
1.67039
-0.361197
1.67039
```

Comment: `std::default_random_engine` : _"implementation-defined"_  source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random  Use one of the 2 mt19937 if you want the same implementaion on different compilers.

Comment: If you remove the undefined behavior part of the code, do you still get incorrect results?

Comment: You almost never want to have reference as a member

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your constructor:

```
FillUpX(default_random_engine eng):generator{eng}{};
```

You take the engine *by value* and then *save a reference to it*. That object will of course be destructed once the constructor returns, making your reference invalid.

Comment: But once it is pass by value, it should still be a random engine. why they do not behave like a random engine but generate repeat same numbers?

Comment: @drbombe Because of [*undefined behavior!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) In the `printValue` function, where you use the reference, the object it references have been destructed and doesn't exist anymore. I suggest you do some more research about scope and life-time of variables and objects.

Comment: @drbombe because that object has been already destroyed. Program better crash because of that, but you are unlucky and get almost good results. Welcome to the "beauty" of UB

Comment: I would say the problem is not in constructor, but that member is a reference